# Sql-server to MySQL migration woes- maximum rowsize cannot exceed 65,535 bytes

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am migrating the database layer of our application from MSSQL to MySQL and came across this exception when I tried to migrate an MSSQL table to MySQL:

```
Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type
,not counting BLOBs, is 65535. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs)
```

Turns out the MSSQL table has lots of nvarchar columns leading of a effective row size much larger than 65535. This only way I could think of to overcome this is to change my application design to split the large table into smaller ones and this redesign isn't something I am looking forward to.

Is there any way to overcome this without application redesign?

Thanks in advance.
Bharath K.

Comment: What about "You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs"?

Comment: That is not very endearing either. Was looking for a mechanism that would not involve framework redesign.

Comment: You don't really have to redesign anything to use TEXT or BLOB. Can you post an example `CREATE TABLE` for the table that's causing  you problems?

Comment: It is an alter query on an already existing table that is causing this.Thanks for your suggestions @Dean, @Simon. Was looking to avoid this change as the queries are generated by our modeling framework. But this does seem the best option out.

Comment: Can you alter the columns on the SQL Server tables? NVARCHAR is typically reserved for Unicode and each character takes up 2 bytes instead of the typical 1 in VARCHAR

Answer (score 2):

According to MySQL's doc: The internal representation of a table also has a maximum row size of 65,535 bytes, even if the storage engine is capable of supporting larger rows. So you just cannot have such a table.

You should analyze your original table's data to change some column's length. Or make some columns of your target MySQL table 'TEXT'